# BSOD after wake up on Windows 7 32bit

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, bsod

**History:**
I had two HDD, one of 500GB with dual boot Windows XP + W7 working ok, and one 1TB HDD for data.
Then I buy a Samsung SSD 850 EVO to upgrade the OS performance and make a fresh W7 install with SSD on AHCI mode.

The install work OK and I make an OS backup in the 1TB HDD.
Then I get a black screen when try to wake up from suspend state; so reading I see that is a common problem with SSD's; so I physically uninstall the SSD and reconfigure the Motherboard to IDE mode and reconnect the 500GB HDD and using the W7 DVD installed the W7 backup that I make before when the SSD was intalled.
That work OK but now I get a BSOD instead of a complete black screen as with the SSD.

I used Crimson Editor to read the dump file and I read something about PS2 mouse but I have not a PS2 mouse, I just tested one old Genius PS2 mouse and unplugged after.

Can be that the reason of the BSOD, that the PS2 is not longer plugged in?

I read here about BlueScreenView and the minidumps (I have 3) remarks this

```
13/10/2015 PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA
MpFilter.sys    MpFilter.sys+8811
ntkrnlpa.exe    ntkrnlpa.exe+16d300

24/10/2015 KERNEL_MODE_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED
ntkrnlpa.exe    ntkrnlpa.exe+123a67
win32k.sys  win32k.sys+365d9

25/10/2015 IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
fltmgr.sys  fltmgr.sys+14b39c48
Ntfs.sys    Ntfs.sys+9c0cb
ntkrnlpa.exe    ntkrnlpa.exe+93492
```

Another thing that I suspect is about SATA cables but I-m not sure 100% because the OS works ok if I don-t suspend the PC.

I perform a complete disk check and virus in safe mode without success.

Any ideas?

**Edit 14/11/2015**

[image: RAM CAS]

Comment: there are some forums where people post mini dumps for an analysis.. and webpages that analyze thme.. But check this out   (I googled about ntkrnlpa.exe and bsod)  http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/blue-screen-caused-by-ntkrnlpaexe/e671b55e-8cfc-41cf-a686-67524c2fe485?auth=1

Comment: share the dmp files, so that I can take a look at them with a debugger

Comment: @magicandre1981 Here's the link http://1drv.ms/1GUDp0l

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crashes are very random, this looks like RAM issues.

From the dump I see that your BIOS is 5 years old:

```
BiosVersion = 1601   
BiosReleaseDate = 09/08/2010
BaseBoardManufacturer = ASUSTeK Computer INC.
BaseBoardProduct = M4A88TD-V EVO/USB3
```

ASUS provides the [BIOS Version 2301](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M4A88TDV_EVOUSB3/HelpDesk_Download/) from 2012 which improves system stability. Try to update the BIOS and look if this improves stablity and fixes the crashes.

The Command Rate (CR) of 1 is also dangerous. Go to the BIOS and set it to 2. This is much more stable and causes less issue.

Comment: What do you use to see the minidump files?

Comment: memory_corruptions at nt!MiPfnShareCountIsZero+99 and IP_MISALIGNED (instruction pointer issue). this looks like RAM issues. Have you tried the BIOS update?

Comment: Yes, I tried but not tested too much.

Comment: I get two more BSOD, after the first one I run the W7 mem test and all ok; then I clean the RAM modules, now I get video for 3 seconds then the image get corrupt and after that I get a BSOD Kernel_mode_exception_not_handled (ntkrnlpa.exe & win32k.sys). Can be the supply responsible for this? I'm running malware bytes now and get zero threats.

Comment: run memtest86+, this is better. Also post pictures of CPU-Z (Memory and SPD tab)

Comment: I do it last night, 5 pases, 4 and a half hours, all ok. I'm at the office now, in about ten hours I will take a screen capture.

Comment: ok, maybe the RAM timings are bad. Pst the picture when you come home after work and I'll look at them .

Comment: I have running the OS since 2011 with zero BSOD, all this problems start when I tried to run a fresh W7 install in a Samsung 850 EVO SSD, so I make an OS backup on a regular 1TB HDD with the Windows tool, formated the old 500GB HDD and install from the SSD backup. Since that moment always have problems with ntkrnlpa.exe & win32k.sys. Anyway I will take a screen capture and post it.

Comment: I check the power supply and found 3 capacitors in the low voltage section that are exploded now I buy new one. Anyway I add the RAM CAS.

Comment: also change the Command Rate (CR) to 2. And if you have such PSU issues, stop using the PC and replace the PSU.

Comment: I change the PSU and update the video driver, until now no more black screens but I get one BSOD -IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL-

Comment: have you also changed the Command Rate to 2?

Comment: No, I can't find the way, the RAM setup in the BIOS is grayed; I just can change from Gaged mode to Ungaged mode. Now I reinstalled the OS too.

Comment: Finally I find the way to change the CR to 2T, I'm testing. I suspend it and wake up 2 times without BSOD or black screen.

Comment: ok, hopefully this was the fix. Test it now for 2 days and reply back if now everything is fine

Comment: Just to have more info I check the memory models and they are Kingston kvr1333d3n9/2g and Gskill F3-10600CL9S-2GBNT; the Gskill page say that the tested CR = 2(2N) but I can't find the CR for the Kingston module.

Comment: CR2 is safe to apply. On 1 can cause such strange issues

Comment: Is the PC stable now with CR set to 2?

Comment: Yes, even with the SSD that never wake up works ok. I get just one reboot. When I wake up the PC I add a SD to the 3 1/2 multi reader and one USB 3.0 pen drive while the OS is waking up. No BSOD or black screen just a reboot, but that's all.

Comment: nice to hear this. I added the CR suggestion so that you can accept the answer to "close" the question